# Sliding Buttons for android activity

Tags: android

I want to create an app in android by sliding image buttons above of my root activity. For example, set of buttons (Like Home, about me and etc) are there in root activity that user can slide them to right or left, then by selecting each of them, a new activity be called. There for my questions are:
1- What is the name of this َability in android programming?
2- To use it, what resources or tutorials can be useful? 
3- Are there any sample code for this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to [Scrollable Tabs](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html#scrollable).

Comment: thanks for your tips but, I need set of horizontally sliding buttons.